# Installing yaws On wondows7

Tags: yaws

I need help, I installed yaws server on windows 7 but when I run yaws -i from command prompt I get the error Failed to create the process entire, Tried to invoke erl.exe then followed by a series of yaws paths and finally says make sure you have erl in your environment PATH.

Please advise on how I can go about this to have yaws serve running.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says add yaws path to the environmental variables PATH.
Then run cmd and type yaws -i